# How can I use Control.Invoke() to throw an exception that won't be ignored?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, exception

**Motivation**

I'm using a `Task` in a `Windows.Forms` application where I want to handle any exceptions thrown by the `Task` by using `Task.ContinueWith()` and `Control.Invoke()` to rethrow any exceptions on the main UI thread.

However, I couldn't get the exception to be noticed if I use `Control.Invoke()` - but it works if I use `Control.BeginInvoke()`.

Does anyone know why it doesn't work with `Control.Invoke()`, and how to get it to work?

**Workaround**

I'm currently using `Control.BeginInvoke()` to throw instead of using `Control.Invoke()`

**Steps to reproduce**

ENVIRONMENT: Windows 7 x64, Visual Studio 2012, Compiled for .Net 4 (but .Net 4.5 is installed as part of VS2012).

(1) Create a default Windows Forms app with a form called `form1`.

(2) Put a button on the form called `button1`, and add a handler for it called `button1_Click()`.

(3) Implement `button1_Click()` as follows:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("TEST");
        }));
    });
}
```

(4) Run the program and click the button. After a second, an exception dialog is displayed as you would expect.

(5) Now change `this.BeginInvoke` to `this.Invoke`.

(6) Run the program again and click the button. Now the exception is silently ignored!

Both `Invoke()` and `BeginInvoke()` execute on the UI thread for the specified `Control`, so I can't understand why in one case the exception is ignored and in the other it is not ignored...

I'm guessing it must be something to do with the fact that `Control.Invoke()` will never return if it throws an exception, but my brain hurts trying to work out why that would mean the exception is (apparently) totally ignored.

Comment: See http://charlieflowers.wordpress.com/2005/04/26/controlinvoke-and-exception-propogation-short-form/

Comment: Aha! So that explains it. The answer therefore is: I can't use `Control.Invoke`; I must use `Control.BeginInvoke`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design, Invoke() handles exceptions differently than BeginInvoke().  It will marshal the exception back and re-throw it so that you know that the invoked method failed.  This cannot work for BeginInvoke() since the thread has moved on already, so it is raised on the UI thread.  The next problem is that the Task class swallows exceptions so you never see it.

You are doing this the hard way. If you like the default exception dialog then just use it with raising an exception at all:

```
this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
    using (var dlg = new ThreadExceptionDialog(new InvalidOperationException("TEST"))) {
        dlg.ShowDialog();
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I don't want to use the default exception dialog though. My actual handling is in a user control in a class library, so I don't know the context of how the exception will be handled; therefore I just need to rethrow it.

Comment: It will not be handled, there is no code running on the UI thread that's going to catch it.  Beyond the default exception handler that shows ThreadExceptionDialog.  A library that injects exceptions from nowhere is not a usable library.  At least raise an event so that the client code has a shot at it.

Comment: Don't worry - it is being handled, and it is already working. The main program handles all exceptions with a custom exception dialog, and it subscribes to `Application.ThreadException`, `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` and also of course has a try/catch around the `Application.Run()` call. The `Task` code has been converted from what used to be `Threads`, which is where the difference in exception handling originated. The exception itself is passed to a delegate passed all the way in from the outer program, so it's not a foreign exception.

Comment: Hmm, that only means it is being reported.  Handling an exception takes a lot more work.  Don't forget that Environment.Exit() call.

Comment: Aye, it's just being reported. We close the program if we get an unexpected exception. But I did omit the important piece of information that the exception isn't thrown from the class library, but instead I use a delegate to call a method in the outermost application (with a parameter of type Exception), and it is *that* which actually rethrows the exception - so it's handled by a context which knows what to expect. (I shouldn't have said "actual handling is in a user control" earlier; that was totally misleading - what I meant to convey was that I could rely on outer handling)