# Control.Invoke unwraps the outer exception and propagates the inner exception instead

Tags: c#, winforms, invoke

The `MessageBox.Show` call below shows "Inner". Is this a bug?

```
private void Throw()
{
    Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        throw new Exception("Outer", new Exception("Inner"));
    }));
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Throw();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); // Shows "Inner"
    }
}
```

Comment: I note that the `await Task.Run()` is not relevant. You should omit it from your question, as it only serves to distract from the issue you are asking about.

Comment: This is interesting. If we add yet another inner exception, it will give us that as well.

Comment: Flaggers: care to actually read the question before flagging it as a duplicate of [this other one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704711/how-can-i-use-control-invoke-to-throw-an-exception-that-wont-be-ignored)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a look at the reference source for `System.Windows.Forms.Control`, and the code that deals with `Invoke` looks like this:

```
try {
    InvokeMarshaledCallback(current);
}
catch (Exception t) {
    current.exception = t.GetBaseException();
}
```

`GetBaseException`:

```
public virtual Exception GetBaseException() 
{
    Exception inner = InnerException;
    Exception back = this;

    while (inner != null) {
        back = inner;
        inner = inner.InnerException;
    }

    return back;
}
```

So apparently it's like this by design. The comments in the source offer no explanation as to why they do this.

EDIT: Some site that is now gone claims this comment came from a guy at Microsoft:

> Based on the winform comfirmation in the record, our analysis is
>   correct of the root cause and this behavior is intended. The reason was to
>   prevent the user from seeing too much of the Windows.Forms internal mechanisms.
>   This is because the winform's default error dialog also leverages Application.ThreadException to show the exception details. .Net Winform
>   team trims the other exceptions information so that the default error
>   dialog will not display all the details to the end user.
>
> Also, some MSFTs have sugguested to change this behavior. However, .Net
>   Winform team thinks that changing the exception to throw is a breaking
>   change and for this reason WinForms will keep sending the innermost exception to the Application.ThreadException handler.

Comment: I note that there are also two now-purged Connect reports on the topic, previously at URLs http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/386582/control-invoke-exception-handling and http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/433765/control-invoke-throws-exception-getbaseexception-rather-than-the-actual-exception (if you try to go to those links, the web site reports the pages are gone or prohibited). You can see small snippets of each by searching MSDN with "control.invoke inner exception" and looking at the summaries.

Comment: Nice findings. Couldn't find that code in ILSPY though.

Comment: @Juan Check out `InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()` under `System.Windows.Forms.Control`.

Answer (score 0):

The OP doesn't seem to be interested in a work-around. Anyhow, this is mine:

```
public static object InvokeCorrectly(this Control control, Delegate method, params object[] args) {
    Exception failure = null;
    var result = control.Invoke(new Func<object>(() => {
        try {
            return method.DynamicInvoke(args);
        } catch (TargetInvocationException ex) {
            failure = ex.InnerException;
            return default;
        }
    }));
    if (failure != null) {
        throw failure;
    }
    return result;
}
```